# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is producing null where with inner join update

Tags: mysql, sql, opencart

I`m trying to upload a file in my opencart database, I want to bulk upload the product UPC numbers and I'm using this query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  `my_temp_table`
(
     product_id INT(11),
     name VARCHAR(255),
     upc VARCHAR(12)
); 

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/mupckuco/dev/oc_product.csv'
INTO TABLE `my_temp_table`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(`product_id`, `name`, `upc`);

UPDATE `oc_product`
INNER JOIN `my_temp_table` on `my_temp_table`.`product_id` = `oc_product`.`product_id`
SET `oc_product`.`upc` = `my_temp_table`.`upc`;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE `my_temp_table`;
```

Firstly I have exported the table with product id, product name and the column with the product UPC with the following query:

```
SELECT  `oc_product`.`product_id` ,  `oc_product_description`.`name` ,  `oc_product`.`upc` 
FROM  `oc_product` 
INNER JOIN  `oc_product_description` ON  `oc_product`.`product_id` =  `oc_product_description`.`product_id`
```

BUT unfortunately, this line

```
UPDATE `oc_product` INNER JOIN `my_temp_table` on `my_temp_table`.`product_id` = `oc_product`.`product_id` SET `oc_product`.`upc` = `my_temp_table`.`upc`
```

is inserting NULLs in the table.

I have tried firstly to create a normal table (not temporary) so there i saw that everything in the UPC column is inserted as NULL.

I'm doing export as CSV for Microsoft Excel and I'm saving the file with the same extension. Where can be the problem?

This are some examples from the csv file and the my_temp_table results after updating:

[image: excel csv]

[image: my_temp_table]

Comment: Please show a sample of rows from the csv **and** a sample of temp table after `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: I have edited the question, hope this is clearly

Comment: Great! Thanks. Try formatting the Excel file columns B and C as *Text*. And add to `LOCAL` command lines: `ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';`

Comment: No, again NULLs...

Comment: How are you importing? I noticed the Linux file path, yet a Windows MS Excel screenshot? Client to a server? Or all one server? Are you running command inside phpmyadmin? Try running from code (i.e., Python, PHP) that connects to db, or MySQL command line using `source`.

Comment: im using phpmyadmin, the file is located on the server

Comment: Oh my god, i was terminating the fields by comma, they must be terminated by " ; " as in the csv file, got it, thanks everybody!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159491/discussion-between---and-parfait).

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I have never seem someone try to import a CSV directly in to the database and then run an update with a JOIN, perhaps your background is as a DBA rather than a PHP developer?

Anyway, I suggest you import the CSV in to an array in PHP:

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('/home/mupckuco/dev/oc_product.csv'));
```

And then loop over it to generate the UPDATE statement.

Comment: Great! How can i do this with php? Im using opencart, i hope i can make it with it?